# Azure Virtual Machine and SQL image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I am new on Azure Virtual Machines. My web site, MVC4, needs to use MS SQL to store some results.
Which image do I need to use when creeating the VM? the 2012 Server or the SQL Server?

Can I install the 2012 Server and then to install the SQL Server?

I am not sure about the differences or if the SQL Server image is also for general purposes. Or maybe do I need to install two machines, one for Windows and the other one for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options for you, and it will depend on how you would like to set up your application.  Cost is also a consideration.

- You could set up 1 VM to run both IIS (you MVC app) and SQL Server.  You can use one of the SQL server images for this. Scaling individually will become an issue later.
- You can set up 1 VM for IIS (Windows Server image) and another for SQL Server (SQL Server image).
- You can set up VM for IIS and use Azure SQL Database Service instead of your own VM.

And of course there are also the options of running Web Roles and Web site for MVC app.  I would also suggest using the [Pricing Calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to get an idea of the costs associated with all the different options.

As far as the images are concerned, you are able to use the ones Azure provides as well as install your own license of SQL Server if you happen to have one.  Also, keep in mind that an image with SQL Server will be higher priced than that of just Windows Server since the license for SQL Server is included.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need Azure VMs?  If you have a simple web site (i.e. blog) that needs a small amount of storage I would suggest a cloud service/SQL Azure Database option, since you will not have to worry about all the infrastructure-type settings when deploying (i.e. firewall rules, load balancing, networking, setting up IIS, high availability etc.)

SQL Database for Azure allows you to spin up a SQL Server instance, which Microsoft manages for you (backups, uptime SLA, hot fixes etc.)